# Laravel $table->double('column', 15, 8); a español

Tags: php, laravel

El tipo de datos en una migración: $table->double('column', 15, 8); Permite ingresar datos decimales con un punto en vez de una coma. ¿Como puedo hacer para que se pueda ingresar una coma en vez de un punto?

Comment: ¿Nos puedes dar un ejemplo de lo que deseas cambiar o lo que no te funciona bien?

Comment: Ejemplo si el usuario ingresa 58607253,32 que se guarde en la base de datos como esta, pero en la base de datos double pide 58607253.32, necesitaria formatear el valor y guardarlo utilice la funcion number_format. Ejemplo '$presupuesto = str_replace (",", ".", $request->presupuesto);
                                         $request->presupuesto = number_format($presupuesto,2,".","");'

Comment: Pero cuando me guarda, me guarda con ceros en la parte decimal. Ejemplo  58607253.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo solucione el problema cuando me guarda con ceros en la parte decimal. Ejemplo: Numero ingresado 58607253,32. Numero guardado en la base de datos: 58607253.00

Causa del problema:
Era porque se estaba utilizando el metodo para llenar fill() al objeto de guardado, pero se soluciona pasando individualmete el valor a la clave del objeto, para luego guardarlo.

Solución:
    Numero ingresado en el formulario: 58607253,32

```
    $decimal = str_replace (",", ".", $request->decimal);

    $request->decimal = number_format($decimal,2,".","");

    $input = $request->all();


    $datos = new datos;
    $datos->fill($input);
    $datos->decimal = $request->decimal;
    $datos->save();
```

Numero guardado en la base de datos: 58607253.32